# How to manage multiple long running feature branches in Git?

Tags: git, merge

The [git flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) works really well for a lot of small developmental branches. However, it starts to slightly break down when there are a multiple branches that are super long features. For example, suppose 2 features (`feature_branch_a` and `feature_branch_b`) both take 3 engineering months to finish and you want to maintain them in sync with the `development`/`master` branch as well as with each other.

You could merge development/master into your feature branches every day. but what is a good practice for keeping `feature_branch_a` and `feature_branch_b`  in sync with each other? such that when you merge `feature_branch_a` back to `develop`/`master` that it doesn't screw over `feature_branch_b` massively in terms of merge conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much conflicting work there is between feature A and B, what about just merging B into A and A into B periodically?

Comment: what if this goes into branches `A, B , C, D, E, F, G` ? then we would have a ton of conflicts everywhere very quickly though :/

Answer (score 1):

You have created feature branches feature_branch_a and feature_branch_b from development/master branch.

Actually it is good practice for keeping development/master branch as well as feature_branch_a and feature_branch_b in sync with each other. Instead of having lots of merge conflicts at the end of 3 engineering months.

when you merge feature_branch_a periodically back to develop/master, then update your another respective branch feature_branch_b from develop/master. And resolve conflicts if any, those conflicts will definatly much less and easy to resolve than the conflicts at the end of 3 engineering months. After resolving conflicts update remote develop/master branch and then also merge develop/master to feature_branch_a. So all three branches are upto date and on same page.

Periodically sync with the development/master branch as well as with other feature branches will save life as the number of feature branches gets increases.

Comment: but what if it is not possible to periodically sync `feature_branch_a` to development/master ? because the whole point of having that long running branch is to avoid putting code somewhere that could get reverse engineered